# Limit of ratio between a power series and a "subset" of the power series

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series

$B$ is an infinite power series that converges everywhere, and $A$ is an infinite power series that converges everywhere which is composed only of terms found in $B$ - both have nonnegative real coefficients and are series in a single, nonnegative real variable, $x$, thus both are strictly increasing in $x$.

Are there conditions on $A$ or $B$ which determine that $A/B$ has a limit, (i.e. it doesn't oscillate) as $x \to \infty$? It certainly doesn't diverge because $B\ge A$.

For my problem, I have a strong feeling, based on some heuristic reasoning and based on strong evidence from a graph, that $A/B$ converges to some limit, but I am having the darnest time proving it.

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

The actual series' I have in mind are:

$$ B = e^x = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} $$

and, for fixed $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$

$$ A = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{jn}}{(jn)!} $$

In other words, $A$ is composed of every $n$th term of $e^x$, starting with the $0$th term.

Comment: Usually it is very difficult to determine the large $x$ behavior of power series since they are, in a sense, local representations of the function.

Comment: Also, consider the example $e^x + e^{x^2}$.  Taking just the odd terms of the power series for this function yields $\sinh x$, and $(e^x + e^{x^2})/\sinh x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I'm concerned with power series that converge everywhere, so they are global representations of the function. And divergence to infinity is fine - I just want to show that that ratio HAS a limit at all - it doesn't exhibit undampened oscillation.

Comment: By my first comment I meant that, while a power series may indeed converge everywhere, it still is defined only in terms of local data (the value of derivatives of the function at a point), and extracting global behavior from it is often difficult.  As for another example, a terrible one is $e^{i x}$.  Taking just the even terms yields $\cos x$, and this ratio is badly behaved.

Comment: Point taken as far as global behavior being hard to infer, but I'd still like to try - a globally convergent power series does, after all, contain all the information that determines the limit. As far as your example, that is a good point and I have updated my post with the refinement that both series have real coefficients.

Comment: Also, and I guess this is more to the point, that both B and A are strictly increasing everywhere

Comment: Is your question about two specific power series?  Could you include them in the question?

Comment: Yes - I've edited above. Thanks for your help and interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you gave the answer can be obtained through some formal manipulations.

**Claim.**

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{jn}}{(jn)!} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \exp\left(xe^{i2\pi k/n}\right).
$$

**Proof.**

Because the series in question are absolutely convergent we may rearrange the terms as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \exp\left(xe^{i2\pi k/n}\right) &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^j e^{i2\pi kj/n}}{j!} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{i2\pi kj/n}.
\end{align}
$$

When $j$ is a multiple of $n$ all of the terms of the inner sum are equal to $1$ so the sum is equal to $n$.  When $j$ isn't a multiple of $n$ we note that the inner sum is the partial sum of a geometric series, so

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{i2\pi kj/n} = \frac{1 - e^{i2\pi j}}{1 - e^{i2\pi j/n}} = 0.
$$

Consequently the only terms remaining in the sum are those where $j$ is a multiple of $n$.  We thus have

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \exp\left(xe^{i2\pi k/n}\right) = n \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{jn}}{(jn)!}.
$$

**Q.E.D.**

Using this formula we find that

$$
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{jn}}{(jn)!}}{\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{j}}{j!}} = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \exp\left(x\left(e^{i2\pi k/n}-1\right)\right) \longrightarrow \frac{1}{n}
$$

as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Unreal, you even skipped ahead to what I was ultimately trying to show. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem :) ${}$